# VBA ROUND DECIMAL

Tags: excel, vba, decimal, rounding

ws.Range("J" & resultRow).NumberFormat = "0.00000000"
 i am using this to display 10 digit decimal places 
but i need the result should be like
-3.7500000055
but i am getting 
-3.7500000000
how to round off after 10 digit decimal

Comment: Your number format only has 8 decimal places - 10 would be "0.0000000000".  Note that this doesn't *round* anything - it only controls how it is displayed on the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks comintern.so how to round 10 digit decimal to display non zero digit after 9th digit.

Comment: Use the [Round function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`ROUND(expression, [decimal places])`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/round_vba.php) function.

eg. `Round(ws.Range("J" & resultRow).Value2, 10)`

---

Keep in mind, the `Round()` function uses "round-to-even logic", that means, if the number ends with `5` on the specified decimal spot, it will round up to `0`.

Alternatively, you can take a look at the `RoundUp` or `RoundDown` worksheet functions